# Applet strange issue with different version of IE

Tags: java, applet, internet-explorer-11

I know when we open an applet on 32 bit IE it requires 32 Bit JRE and vice-versa with 64 Bit.

Strange issue i noticed on my machine, is this, When i open an Applet on 64 bit IE(with 64 bit JRE) it makes an file in temp/hsperfdata_user folder but when i open same Applet on 32 bit IE(with 32 bit JRE) it not make a file in temp/hsperfdata_user folder.

I could not locate , why this happen, i stuck any help will be appreciated.

I have following version installed on my machine.

IE 11

JRE 32 bit with 1.8.0_172 version

JRE 64 bit with 1.8.0_162 version

Comment: Note that applets are an obsolete technology, and you will soon encounter strange issues with any browser.

Comment: Hi @Arnaud, i know applets are obsolete but this scenario working fine on different machine. I analyse root cause of this problem why there were not any entry(PID file) in hsperfdata_user when an applet run in 32 bit IE

Comment: @Arnaud *"..and you will soon encounter strange issues with any browser."* I disagree, but only with the use of 'soon'. I've had a long history with applets (including that I wrote the info. page for them & am highest ranked on answering applet questions) and can confirm that they were *always* a complete PITA when it came to niggling problems with how different browsers treated them. With Oracle deprecating applets in Java 9, those problems will get worse though. They no longer have any motivation to even try and correct these types of things.

Comment: @AndrewThompson , you and arnaud both are right that oracle depricate applet in new jre version(above 8), i just want to analyse, why there is no pid for profiling when jp2launcher is running but task manager is listed that.

Comment: *"i just want to analyse"* Well .. go for it, and good luck. I (& most others) could not be bothered.